# How to populate one 8gb and one 16gb dimm in a Dell R230?

Tags: memory, dell

The [Dell R230 User Manual](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r230_owners-manual_en-us.pdf) page 57 states about mixing dimms with different capacities:

> When mixing memory modules with different capacities, populate the sockets with memory modules with the highest capacity first.
>       For example, if you want to mix 4 GB and 8 GB DIMMs, populate 8 GB DIMMs in the sockets with white release levers and 4 GB
>       DIMMs in the sockets with black release levers.

So if i have 4 dimms, two small and two large, how to populate is clear.

However, I have only two dimms. 1x8gb and 1x16gb.

Pretty sure the 16gb goes into slot A1(white). But what about the 8gb? I guess it would be either i to A2(white) or A3(black).

The guideline to populate two same sized dimms is to use A1(white) and A2(white).

Comment: Boot it up with the 8GB chip in A2, if it doesn't work, use A3

Comment: An identical 16 GB stick of RAM is what? $100? That's probably cheaper than any amount of troubleshooting of a production server that's misbehaving during operational hours. Get identical memory sticks at least within the same memory channel, and preferably for all populated channels.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to mix dimms with different size just make sure to populate first the bigger size.  In your case it's **A1**(16GB)  &  **A3** (8GB)

According to Documentation [[LINK]](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/servertg_en-us.pdf):

> Memory modules of different capacities can be mixed. For example, 4 GB
>   and 8 GB memory modules can be mixed. While installing memory modules
>   of different capacities, ensure that you populate the sockets with
>   memory modules with highest capacity first. For example, if you want
>   to mix 4 GB and 8 GB memory modules, populate 8 GB memory modules in
>   the sockets with white release tabs and 4 GB memory modules in the
>   sockets with black release tabs. You can mix maximum of two memory
>   modules of different capacity.

You can find other information in the Owner's Manual (page 58): [LINK](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r230_owners-manual_en-us.pdf)